# Retrieve Single User Data Using Session After He Logged In

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

i am new to this field and this is the first time i am working with session, the question may seem very basic but would appreciate if someone could help me. Currently I have made a login and logout page using session and wish to display data of the particular user who has logged in. The user is redirected to retailer_login.php after they sign in, apart from login form there are 4 pages for the entire login and logout process.

retailer_login.php, retailer_session.php, retailer_profile.php, retailer_logout.php

Every page is working fine however i am able to display only single data column of the user from database but i wish to display the entire information that is stored about that specific user.

DATABASE

```
    Id  name  email          password  country  city   state  occupation
    1   sam   sam@gmail.com  sam       XYZ      ZBC    QWE    student
```

retailer_login page

```
<?php
session_start(); // Starting Session

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    try {
        if (empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
            throw new Exception("email or Password is invalid");
        } else {
            // Define $email and $password
            $email      = $_POST['email'];
            $password   = $_POST['password'];
            // To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
           $email      = stripslashes($email);
           $password   = stripslashes($password);
           $mail      = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
           $password   = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
         //Etablishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
          $connection = mysql_connect("abc.com", "abc", "abc");
          // Selecting Database
            $db= mysql_select_db("abc", $connection);
            // SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
            $query = mysql_query("select * from retailerregister where password='$password' AND email='$email'", $connection);
            $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

            if ($rows != 1)
                throw new Exception("email or Password is invalid");

            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $email; // Initializing Session
            header("location: retailer_profile.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
            mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $_SESSION['login_error'] = $e->getMessage();
        header("Location: index.html");
    }
}
?>
```

retailer_profile page

```
<?php
include('retailer_session.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Welcome to your homepage</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div id="profile">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class = "navbar-brand"> <id="welcome">Welcome : <i><?php echo $login_session; ?></i> </a>

                <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class = "icon-bar"> </span>
                    <span class = "icon-bar"> </span>
                    <span class = "icon-bar"> </span>
                </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class ="active"> <a href="retailer_profile.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Property <b class ="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li> <a href="retailer_property_add.php">Add property</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">View property</a> </li>
                            </ul>   
                    </li>   
                    <li> <a href="retailer_logout.php"><id="logout">Log Out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>              
</div>

<div name="container">


</div>

<script src = "js/jquery-1.11.1.js"> </script>
<script src = "js/bootstrap.js"> </script>

</body>
</html>
```

retailer_logout page

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if(session_destroy()) // Destroying All Sessions
    {
    header("Location: index.html"); // Redirecting To Home Page
    }
    ?>
```

retailer_session page

```
<?php
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("abc.com", "abc", "abc");
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("abc", $connection);
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql=mysql_query("select * from retailerregister where email='$user_check'", $connection);

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['email'];

if(!isset($login_session)){
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
header('Location: index.html'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

right now i am only able to use `$login_session` in order to display email on profile page. Can anyone please tell my how to display other data of the logged in user on the retailer_profile page through session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create another variables about current logged in user:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['email'];

// another user data

$user_name = $row['name'];
$user_country = $row['country'];
$user_city = $row['city'];
$user_state = $row['state'];
$user_occupation = $row['occupation'];
```

Or you can just use one variable which shouldn't be overwritten:

```
$user_data = $row;
```

And then somewhere in script:

```
echo $user_data['city']; // etc...
```